# Autofilter to hide rows if cell above is blank

Tags: excel, vba

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to hide a row if the above row is blank, otherwise un-hide that row. It seems that it should be simple but I can't seem to do it.

After research I did come across this code that looks to me it should work, however I am not getting any response out of it.

`Range("A15:A21").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False`

The range is correct in the above code.

Comment: You **cannot** use autofilter to filter based on what is in the row above. However, if column A has unique values then you could loop through and collect the rows with a blank above it into a union then hide the union.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm not too familiar with what you are suggesting. Column A will always have text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this macro should do the trick

```
Sub hide_if_blank_above()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 21 To 15 Step -1
        Dim should_hide As Boolean
        should_hide = IsEmpty(Range("A" & i - 1))
        Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = should_hide
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, however is there a way to make this automatic?

Comment: I suppose you could put it inside the "open" event of your workbook or any other events that you regularly fire (For example : Worksheet selection changed, worksheet activate or worksheet change)

Comment: I can't seem to get a response out of it. I added
`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
in replacement of Sub, It does nothing

Comment: I let Excel automatically create the sub by going to the worksheet's code, selecting the worksheet object (through the dropdown that says "general") and then clicking on the selection_change event in the right dropdown (which lists all event). Then I just copied the code I had in my example in the sub which left me with `Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: I don't believe the public scope modifier changes anything so maybe the problem lies in the way you created the method